# Simple "menu-screen" code not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I am trying to make a simple game. While making the game. I made the first scene, which is just a blank scene, with the words "play." on them. I did `ctrl+b` to make the letters each have their own "box". And converted them all into a symbol, named: `play_btm` as well as naming the symbol the same thing. When I run it though, and click on it, it does not take me to the second scene like it should. Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
play_btm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,pClicked);
function pClicked(e:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably does, but you can click ONLY on the letters, which is little a bit harder :).
Fast way to cope with it is to make new layer in MovieClip with transparent rectangle under the text.